# I can ssh into a remote machine but I can't use scp to copy local stuff to the remote machine

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm using a remote machine, which is in a lab
and the administrator ask a RSA public key and then I can login into that machine
using a passphrase I set

now I want to use scp to copy local stuff to the remote machine
but when I use scp, the error is

```
ssh: connect to host 138.46.231.12 port 22: No route to host
```

are there any ways to do that?
I'm using fedora, the remote machine is on ubuntu
thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting? Do you have rights to the destination path on the remote computer?

Comment: I have updated the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should just be:

```
scp /local/path/to.file <user>@<ubuntu machine>:/remote/path/
```

from terminal on your Fedora machine. Do you receive an error? What is the output after running the command?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe has nothing to do with ssh or scp.

Obviously you had a network configuration issue (probably a default route which wasn't correctly set).

Comment: How would `ssh` work if this were the problem?